# IntellIJ IDEA не учитывает модель в JSP-шаблоне

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jsp

IntellIJ IDEA JSP не видит объекты, которые я передаю из контроллера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код компилируется и все работает, просто писать в таком режиме не очень комфортно.

Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Какие плагины у вас установлены?

Comment: Все что по умолчанию стоят.